# How can I add an overlay clipping mask to a multi color map in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, overlay, clipping-mask

I have a large area city map where every neighborhood is a different color. I want a textured overlay on top. When I use the texture as a clipping mask the bottom neighborhoods disappear and only the texture is left. Is there a way to put the texture as an overlay on top of the color shapes without changing the colors?

Comment: Does Illustrator not have a "blending mode" option like Photoshop?  It certainly has "opacity."

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. 
I needed to make the same shape of the map and then using pathfinder crop the texture and the shape together!